# query sql combine multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below

## book

- idbook
- idapplicant
- idsiteplan
- date

## applicant

- idapplicant
- name_applicant

## siteplan

- idsiteplan
- plan

## detail

- iddetail
- idbook
- name
- value

how to implement the query so that it becomes as below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name_applicant| siteplan| date       | detail                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| aaa           | tapak1  | 12-12-2013 | name_of_detail_1 : value_of_detail_1 |
|                                        name_of_detail_2 : value_of_detail_2 |
|                                        name_of_detail_3 : value_of_detail_3 |
|                                        name_of_detail_4 : value_of_detail_4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bbb           | tapak2 | 13-12-2013 | name_of_detail_1 : value_of_detail_1  |
|                                       name_of_detail_2 : value_of_detail_2  |
|                                       name_of_detail_3 : value_of_detail_3  |
|                                       name_of_detail_4 : value_of_detail_4  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you also translate your result column name? Thanks! :)

Comment: Google `MySQL Joins` and do it on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a good starting point I think :

```
SELECT a.name_applicant,
       s.plan as siteplan,
       b.date,
       CONCAT(d.name,' : ',d.value) as detail
FROM applicant a
INNER JOIN book b ON b.idapplicant = a.idapplicant
INNER JOIN siteplan s ON s.idsiteplan = b.idsiteplan
INNER JOIN detail d ON b.idbook = d.idbook
```